# BeautifulSoup Access Denied

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

trying to do some web scraping with beautiful soup. I had an issue accessing the page https://www.niche.com/k12/search/largest-public-high-schools/s/connecticut/ as I was told "access to this page has been denied." I worked around this with the following code:

```
def extract_source(url):
    headers = { 
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36', 
'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip', 
'DNT' : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header 
'Connection' : 'close'
}
    source = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
    return source
```

However, a few hours later I am back to being told "access to this page has been denied." Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Probably there's been too many requests coming from your ip and your access has been temporary blocked. Try to use longer and variable delays between page accesses.

Answer (score 0):

The site that you are aiming to scrape is protected by Perimeter X. You can see this listed in the `Detected technologies` section of this [URL scan](https://urlscan.io/result/0a2fa3f4-7fc4-42ab-b9c5-a97d196bb956).

It is most likely that you're triggering the bot protection from this security service. You will want to slow down the frequency of your requests. You will also want to change the User Agent to a newer one.

```py
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
```

However, there are more ways to fingerprint and block your visit than just user agent. The purpose of the security service they are using is to prevent web scaping like what you're doing. You may want to switch to [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and slow your scaping down.